# Ajax call returns nothing for secured sites URL,How to access secured sites in ajax?

Tags: ajax

```
function loadMessages(){

  $.ajax({
      url :"https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/search.json?search=java",
      async: false,
      dataType: "json",
      crossDomain: true,
      success : function (data) {
          alert(data);
         var htmldata = "";
        for(var cntr=0;cntr<data.messages.messages.length;cntr++){

            htmldata += "<tr><td>"+data.messages.messages[cntr].content_excerpt+"</td></tr>"
        }
        alert("no of msgs"+data.messages.messages.length);
        $("#text tbody").append(htmldata);
        return data;
      }
});
}
```

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/search.json?search=java. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8002' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Comment: what is this last line supposed to be?

Comment: Did you configure your SSL layer to use https?

Comment: dataType: "json" is difficult to confirm the error in detail.  Replace it by "text" and show the response data and check them.

Comment: @KNaito: I have changed datatype to text,but response data is blank..

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I haven't configured SSL layer,pls suggest me.